# hadoop-ec2 in Hadoop package: how to specify a region?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2

I want to launch Hadoop cluster on EC2 in some Asian AWS region but it is being set up in East Coast one (Virginia) by default and I can't find any relevant parameter or environment variable for that from bin/hadoop-ec2 command (launch-cluster in particular). Please advise!

Comment: Are you sure you want to setup a Hadoop cluster on EC2 instances manually? That's what Elastic Map Reduce is for.

Comment: Yes at this point we want to evaluate both and decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your EC2 url in EC_URL environment variable like this:

```
export EC2_URL="https://ap-southeast-1.ec2.amazonaws.com/"
```

Then it will extract the info here and it is used by ec2-run-instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you start your instance by ec2-run-instances, you can specify --availability-zone. It is really a lot of work doing everything manually for hadoop. Do you want to try Apache Whirr?

Comment: It looks like the trend is using whirr? I will definitely try that. In the meantime I found an answer for my question.